# after redirect - is there a way to remove the form field from the URL in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

After sending a form, i'm redirected to another page.

The URL of that page will contain the URL + form field name + form field value.

Is there a way to redirect (or maybe manipulating data without redirect) in a way that the URL won't show the form field name and value?

my project (no apps):

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^translate/', views.translate, name='translate'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'hello.html')


def translate(request):

original = request.GET['originaltext'].lower()
translation = ''
for word in original.split():
    if word[0] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
        translation += word
        translation +='yay '
    else:
        translation += word[1:]
        translation += word[0]
        translation += 'ay '

return render(request, 'translate.html', {'original':original, 
'translate':translation})
```

hello.html

```
<h1> heading title </h1>

<form action="{% url 'translate' %}">
  <input type="text" name="originaltext"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Translate" />
</form>
```

translate.html

```
{{ original }} <br>
{{ translate }}
<br><br>
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
```

So whenever i'm sending the form, i'm redirected and the URL becomes:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/translate/?originaltext=user_text

Comment: You can use `return redirect('urlname')` instead of **render** and you are also using request.GET.

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal, what do you mean "you are also using request.GET"? should i remove it? right now using redirect i'm getting an error -MultiValueDictKeyError at /translate/translate.html

Comment: Where do you do the redirect ?

Comment: You are receiving arguments as GET parameters, that's why you are redirected to the above mentioned url. One thing you can do is to redirect to the home page after the current view or set the code as `request.GET.get('originaltext', None).lower().

Comment: You have to render the form in html and submit the form in the same view. The manipulation of form you are trying to do in translate view should go inside home view itself. After the manipulation if you want to do the redirect, you can do that from the home view.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal - i've changed the above render to redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to send POST request from your form:

```
<form action="{% url 'translate' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="originaltext"/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Translate" />
</form>
```

In your view:

```
def translate(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        original = request.POST.get('originaltext').lower()
        context['original'] = original
        translation = ''
        for word in original.split():
            if word[0] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
                translation += word
                translation +='yay '
            else:
                translation += word[1:]
                translation += word[0]
                translation += 'ay '
        context['translation'] = translation
    return render(request, 'translate.html', context)
```

Comment: it works! can you please explain what you did there?

Comment: Initially you sent the request as GET. I made it as POST. The GET request exposes params in the url, while the POST doesn't. And in the view I made sure the POST request is properly handled.